# diff and NFS volume

Tags: linux, diff, nfs

I have a nightly job that runs regressions tests, stores the results to an NFS mounted volume and then does a diff against today's and yesterday's results. I am getting `"No such file or directory"` on both files yet they exist!

```
diff: /mnt/remoteVol/results/Regression/NightlyRegressions/yesterdaysDate/summaries.txt: No such file or directory
16:49:47 diff: /mnt/remoteVol/results/Regression/NightlyRegressions/todaysDate/summaries.txt: No such file or directory
```

Yet, if I 
cd to `/mnt/remoteVol/results/Regression/NightlyRegressions/yesterdaysDate`

and then 
diff summaries.txt ../todaysDate/summaries.txt

It works!?

There are NO symbolic links in the path and the original diff WORKS on the NFS server.

I found my fix but would like to know why this doesn't work in the original form

Thanks in advance.